# How to run Domain Controller and Host Controller in single machine in jboss7?

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I have single machine with single IP address(192.168.1.3) . I copied `domain` directory as `host1`.
Changed `domain.xml , host.xml` to differentiate between domain controller and host controller . Now i have to run both domain controller and host controller in the single machine on single ip address , how can i make this configuration ? Could you suggest what other changes i have to make ?

Answer (score 3):

Download EAP installer. Extract it.  Make two copies of domain directories node1 and node2. Then execute these commands:

```
cd $JBOSS_HOME
cp -r ./domain ./node1
cp -r ./domain ./node2
```

To start this domain instances, you just have to change native port and management port in `host.xml`.

```
<management-interfaces>
    <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
        <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:10999}"/>
    </native-interface>
    <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
        <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:10990}"/>
    </http-interface>
</management-interfaces>
```

or you can mention them at runtime like:

```
./bin/domain.sh -Djboss.domain.base.dir=./node1/ -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.1.3 -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.1.3 <REST_OF_PARAMATERS>
./bin/domain.sh -Djboss.domain.base.dir=./node2/ -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.1.3 -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.1.3 -Djboss.management.native.port=10999 -Djboss.management.http.port=10990 <REST_OF_PARAMATERS>
```

Also you need to make sure that the servers defined in `host.xml` must have different port offsets for 'node1 domain' and 'node2 domain'.

Otherwise you would get an

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use

error.